# How to check if a folder exists at a regular interval in java

Tags: java, hadoop

My goal is to check if a Hadoop path exists and if yes, then it should download some file. Now in every five minutes, I want to check if the file exists in the Hadoop path.
currently,  my code is checking if the file exists but not on an interval basis.

```
public boolean checkPathExistance(final org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path hdfsAbsolutePath)
{
    final Configuration configuration = getHdfsConfiguration();
    try
    {
        final FileSystem fileSystems = hdfsAbsolutePath.getFileSystem(configuration);
        if (fileSystems.exists(hdfsAbsolutePath))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The criteria are this checkPathExistance method should be called in every five minutes to check if the file exists. And when it will return true, the file should be downloaded.

```
 public void download(final String hdfs, final Path outputPath)
{
    final org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path hdfsAbsolutePath = getHdfsFile(hdfsLocalPath).getPath();
    logger.info("path check {}", hdfsAbsolutePath.getName());
    final boolean isPathExist =  checkPathExistance(hdfsAbsolutePath);
    downloadFromHDFS(hdfsAbsolutePath, outputPath);
}
```

Can I please get some help here ?

Comment: Make sure to avoid downloading the same file multiple times.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Does this API work under Hadoop?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the file copying (and not *folder* copying, if I understood correctly within your question's context) you can just use the `copyToLocalFile` method from `FileSystem` as seen [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) by specifying the boolean that checks if you want to delete the source file, and the input (HDFS)/output (local) paths.

As for the periodic checking of the existence of the file in HDFS, you can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` object (Java 8 docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)) by specifying that you want your functions' execution to run every 5 minutes.

The following program takes two arguments, the path of the input file in the HDFS and the path of the output file locally.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RegularFileCheck
{
    public static boolean checkPathExistence(Path inputPath, Configuration conf) throws IOException
    {
        boolean flag = false;

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        if(fs.exists(inputPath))
            flag = true;

        return flag;
    }

    public static void download(Path inputPath, Path outputPath, Configuration conf) throws IOException
    {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        fs.copyToLocalFile(false, inputPath, outputPath);   // don't delete the source input file
        System.out.println("File copied!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable task = () ->
        {
            System.out.println("New Timer!");

            try
            {
                if(checkPathExistence(inputPath, conf))
                    download(inputPath, outputPath, conf);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

The console output of course is continuous and looks like the one on the screenshot below (`test.txt` is the file stored in HDFS, `test1.txt` is the file to be copied locally). You can additionally modify the code above if you want to stop the re-executions after the file has been found and copied already, or if you want to stop checking for the file after a while.
[image]

To stop the search and copying, simply replace to the code above with the following snippet:

```
Runnable task = () ->
{
    System.out.println("New Timer!");

    try
    {
        if(new File(String.valueOf(outputPath)).exists())
            System.exit(0);
        else if(checkPathExistence(inputPath, conf))
            download(inputPath, outputPath, conf);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

And the program will stop after the file has been copied, as seen from the console output:
[image]